# Ads Server settings not used in .net application using Advantage.Data.Provider

Tags: .net, database-connection, limit, advantage-database-server

We're connecting to an Ads server with a .net application using the Advantage .NET Data Provider.

The ServerType = REMOTE. The max. connections on the server is set to 150.

When we connect from a client we get a "6303 Maximum Advantage Database Server connections exceeded" error. Turns out it uses the default 50 max. connections for an application.

When we place an ads.ini file with MAX_CONNECTIONS set to 150 in the folder of the .net application (where also the Advantage.Data.Provider.dll sits), these settings are used.

It doesn't fall back to ServerType = LOCAL, because we tested this by removing the adsloc.dll and adslocal.cfg files.

Why doesn't the AdsConnection use the server settings (being 150)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client and server have a different number of allowed connections. They have separate settings.

The client side setting limits the total number of connection the client application can open to one or more servers.

The server side setting limits the total number of connection the server can have open from all connected clients.

On newer servers (since 10.0?) the number of connections is a soft limit and may be raised when necessary.

Comment: So, even if the server is set up to allow 150 connections. The application running on the client side will always use the default 50 connections unless specified otherwise in ads.ini on the client. Do I understand this correctly?